# Testing Stripe transfer API webhook with real data

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe with the separate charges and transfers flow. The way this goes is that my platform receives the full payment minus the Stripe fees, and then I do a Transfer to the seller's connected account, which is then paid out to their bank. I set up a webhook to run on the "transfer.paid" event, so I can update some book-keeping records on my platform's database when the money is transferred to the connected account. I wish to test this endpoint so that I can see whether my event behaves as expected. However, it seems that the webhook testing available through the Stripe Dashboard sends only dummy data, or only populates a few items of the request body with data from the last transaction made in the account. It seems the only way to receive real data is to allow the event to trigger by itself. In my case, though,the transfers are taking up to seven days to complete, which means I have to send and wait a whole week to see the result, which is really slowing down my development time. This seems really inefficient, unless there is something fundamental that I am not understanding about webhooks. Does anyone have any idea how I can test my webhook endpoints with real data without having to wait so long? Any info will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to test events with 'real' payloads for some things like Subscription-based events and Payouts is to wait for the event to occur in testmode.